# Both example.com and www.example.com with SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https

I obtained a free CA certificate from https://www.startssl.com/.

I added the domain name `example.com`, and in the control panel, it shows `www.example.com` under SSL/TLS Server, and `example.com` under Domain Validations.

I configured Apache (running on Centos) per the instructions, and can access https://example.com/ without a "Untrusted Connection" warning, but when accessing https://www.example.com/, I get the warning.

How can I either rewrite https://www.example.com/ to https://example.com/, or configure the certificate to also work with http://example.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were meant to obtain an SSL certificate for `www.example.com`, not `example.com`.

[image: Add subdomain in StartSSL certificates wizard]

When you do this, StartSSL will give you a certificate that works for both hostnames.

[image: Ready to create certificate]

Comment: Thanks Michael.  My only domain listed is `example.com`, and it displays `Select the top target domain name for your certificate.`.  Do I need to validate `www.example.com`?  When attempting to do so, it says I cannot validate a subdomain.

Comment: You should have already validated your domain. I'm talking about obtaining the SSL certificate!

Comment: I validated `example.com`.  I requested a certificate for `example.com`.  When proceeding, it states `You must add one sub domain to this certificate. The base domain example.com will be included by default in the Alt Name section.`.  I entered `www.example.com`.  But `www.example.com` results in the warning.

Comment: I assume rewriting is not an option for me since the user will get the warning before it hits my server, right

Comment: What warning are you talking about now?

Comment: The warning from the client's browser stating that the connection is untrusted.  I think I figured it out.  I added `www.example.com` as a ServerAlias, and it seems to work.  `www.example.com` must have been hitting my server, but not accessing the certificates.